# Internet explorer wont show the rendered gsp with embeded jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, grails, internet-explorer-8

I send an Ajax request and the result is a table presented using data-table jquery plug-in. If the response is successful I will open a NEW WINDOW and display the result there. This works perfectly in FF but fails in IE 8. IE throws object expected error. For some reason it does not recognize the jquery libraries. But if I refresh the IE page once it will render the table successfully. 
Am I missing anything here? what is different when I open a new window in IE?

```
    function   openResult (html){
        var output =  window.open("",null, "resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0");
         if (window.focus) {output.focus()}
         output.document.open();    
         output.document.write(html);
         output.document.close();    

   return false;
   };
```

.....

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "${g.createLink(action: 'search' )}?&time="+ date,
           data: dataString,  
           success: function(response) {
               $("#displayBox").hide()
               openResult(response)
               //$('#listTemplateDivId').html(response) ;              
               $.unblockUI()

           }
 });
```

Comment: Popup windows are an annoyance. Please consider using something inline, e.g. jQuery UI dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ThiefMaster Thanks for the suggestion. I endup using colorbox and its working perfectly.